# Reading multiple data frames from a single file with R

Tags: r, read.table

My problem is that I'm trying to read in data which has been formatted by an archaic piece of Fortran code (and thus is character limited on each line). The data consists of a number of chunks, each with a fixed width format, and the basic structure of each chunk is:

```
header line (one line, 11 columns)
data (80 lines, 11 columns)
header line (identical to above)
blank (3 lines)
```

The first column is identical for each chunk, so once read in, I can join the dfs into a single df. However, how do I read all of the chunks of the data in? Am I limited to writing a loop with a skip value that goes up in increments of 85, or is there a neater way to do things?

Comment: I don't think you understood the issue. The issue is not reading fixed-format data, the issue is reading chunks of data with blank lines between them.

Comment: Yes, that's a good alternative.